# Gravatar images are not fetched in Ultimate Member plugin

Tags: wordpress, gravatar, ultimate-member

Under users tab (Ultimate Member -> Settings -> Users) "Use Gravatars" is enabled, still it shows empty/default gravatar than user's gravatar avatar/image.

Is it an issue or Is there any way to allow Ultimate Member plugin to use gravatar avatars/images?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone searching for the answer, things have changed a bit in Ultimate Member 2.0. To enable Gravatars in the new version, you need to go to Ultimate Member –> Settings –> General –> Users and enable "User Gravatars". If the user hasn't uploaded a custom profile photo, a gravatar will be used for them.